# Docker-compose with Airflow - MS SQL Server (connection failed)

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I´m not able to connect in the SQL Server inside Airflow using docker-compose. I want to take data from SQL Server direct to Cloud Storage and then the data will be sent to Big Query.

How to solve this?

```
import json
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_check_operator import BigQueryCheckOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.file_to_gcs import FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.mysql_to_gcs import MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator


default_args = {
    'owner': 'Test Data',
    'depends_on_past': True,    
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 5, 29),
    'end_date': datetime(2019, 5, 30),
    'email': ['email@clientx.com.br'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

# Set Schedule: Run pipeline once a day. 
# Use cron to define exact time. Eg. 8:15am would be "15 08 * * *"
schedule_interval = "* * * * *"

# Define DAG: Set ID and assign default args and schedule interval
dag = DAG(
    'bigquery_github_trends', 
    default_args=default_args, 
    schedule_interval=schedule_interval
    )


extract = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='chama_extract',
    mysql_conn_id='mysql_hml',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='my_gcp_conn',
    sql="""SELECT * FROM test""",
    bucket='my_bucket',
    filename='test/test{}.json',
    schema_filename='schemas/test.json',
    dag=dag)

load = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
            task_id='chama_load',
            bigquery_conn_id='my_gcp_conn',
            google_cloud_storage_conn_id='my_gcp_conn',
            bucket='my_bucket',
            destination_project_dataset_table="tst.teste123",
            source_objects=['test/test0.json'],
            schema_object='schemas/test.json',
            source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
            create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
            write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
            dag=dag)


# Setting up Dependencies
load.set_upstream(extract)
```

Docker-compose.yml

```html
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  webserver:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.1
    build:
      context: https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow.git#1.10.1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        AIRFLOW_DEPS: gcp_api,s3        
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Local
      - FERNET_KEY=jsDPRErfv8Z_eVTnGfF8ywd19j4pyqE3NpdUBA_oRTo=
    volumes:
      - ./examples/intro-example/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      # Uncomment to include custom plugins
      # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: webserver
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
```

docker-compose-gcloud.yml

```html
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  webserver:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.1
    build:
      context: https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow.git#1.10.1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        AIRFLOW_DEPS: gcp_api,s3        
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Local
      - FERNET_KEY=jsDPRErfv8Z_eVTnGfF8ywd19j4pyqE3NpdUBA_oRTo=
    volumes:
      - ./examples/gcloud-example/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      # Uncomment to include custom plugins
      # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: webserver
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
```

And execute in docker the command:

> docker-compose -f docker-compose-gcloud.yml up
>   --abort-on-container-exit

Error message in Airflow:

> [2019-05-29 07:00:37,938] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [2019-05-29 07:00:37,937] {{base_hook.py:83}} INFO - Using connection to: 10.0.0.1
>   [2019-05-29 07:00:58,974] {{models.py:1760}} ERROR - (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on 10.0.0.1 (111 "Connection refused")')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1659, in _run_raw_task
>       result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 105, in execute
>       cursor = self._query_mysql()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 127, in _query_mysql
>       conn = mysql.get_conn()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/mysql_hook.py", line 103, in get_conn
>       conn = MySQLdb.connect(**conn_config)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 84, in Connect
>       return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 164, in **init**
>       super(Connection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
>   MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on 10.0.0.1 (111 "Connection refused")')
>   [2019-05-29 07:00:58,988] {{models.py:1789}} INFO - All retries failed; marking task as FAILED
>   [2019-05-29 07:00:58,992] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [2019-05-29 07:00:58,991] {{configuration.py:255}} WARNING - section/key [smtp/smtp_user] not found in config
>   [2019-05-29 07:00:58,998] {{models.py:1796}} ERROR - [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1659, in _run_raw_task
>       result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 105, in execute
>       cursor = self._query_mysql()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 127, in _query_mysql
>       conn = mysql.get_conn()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/mysql_hook.py", line 103, in get_conn
>       conn = MySQLdb.connect(**conn_config)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 84, in Connect
>       return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 164, in **init**
>       super(Connection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
>   MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on 10.0.0.1 (111 "Connection refused")')

Comment: can you show your docker compose?

Comment: @michalk, done!

Comment: Question tags say sql-server, but your code (and error messages) say mysql (or postgres, depending on whether I'm reading your python or docker compose file).

Answer (score 0):

From the error, the key part to me seems to be the "get_conn" piece. This indicates that when airflow is trying to establish the connection to the database it fails. This means either your connection is not specified (it looks like it might be) or that some part of it is incorrect.

You should check the password, server address, and port are all correct. These should be in either you airflow.cfg, as environment variables, or set in the webserver (Admin panel)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but how do I make changes and access airflow.cfg?

Comment: Since you're running this in docker, it will be in the airflow container. Probably wherever airflow home is in there. It might be better for you to do it via the front-end if you're not comfortable with docker